# Determining limits of double integral joint distribution for $x^2 \le y \le 1$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I have this example in my textbook and am not sure in both cases how the limits of the double integral were set. I am a bit graphically challenged and don't really know how to read things in 3D, so if anyone can provide an intuitive/mathematical explanation, that would be amazing.

> For $x^2 \le y \le 1$, we have the joint PDF $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{x^2}^{1} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$.

1. Can someone explain why the limits of the x integral are -1 and 1, instead of $-\sqrt y$ and $\sqrt y$?

> Taking the same function, if we want to calculate the probability $x>y$, the integrals are set up like $\int_{0}^1 \int_{x^2}^{x} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$.

2. Why is that and where do these limits (0 and 1) come from? How can $x^2$ even be a lower bound to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality $x^2 \le y \le 1$ could be talking about either positive or negative $x$. The implied bounds on $x$ are given by $x^2 \le 1$ which means $|x| \le 1$ or $x \in [-1,1]$.

Now when you need $x>y$, since $x^2 \le y$, you know $y>0$, so since $x>y$, we see $x$ cannot be negative.

---

You generally seem to have a problem understanding how double integrals work. The bounds on the pdf read $-1 < x < 1$ and $x^2 < y < 1$, which describe the constraints you mentioned directly, since the order of the integration is $dy\ dx$. You can rewrite the integral to integrate $dx\ dy$, then the bounds will change to $0 < y < 1$ and $-\sqrt{y} < x < \sqrt{y}$ as you are suggesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes indeed, I don't really get how double integrals work and am trying to figure it out. I wasn't aware that the limits change depending on order of integration.

Comment: Still not clear to me though why in the case of $x>y$, y is between $x^2$ and $x$, and not $x^2$ and 1.